# Active ingredient of Chamomile

Tags: supplement, anxiety-disorders, tea

I'm curious if there is any scientific investigation into the active ingredient in chamomile tea,‎ and whether there is any research into chemically similar supplements.‎ Asking out of interest in chemistry,‎ not for personal medical advice.‎

I've tried reading this [NCBI article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2995283/#:%7E:text=Optimum%20chamomile%20extracts%20contain%20about,-7-O-glucoside.) which suggests that the active ingredient is apigenin,‎ and this [NCBI article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6472148/) that discusses the chemistry of apigenin, both interesting but slightly over my head.‎ Then I looked into chemicals which were said to have a similar mechanism to apigenin,‎ and the chemical Fisetin came up several times,‎ though my chemistry is not strong enough to understand what neurotransmitters are involved and whether they might have the same activity site.‎ I've also seen articles suggesting all flavanoids have a similar behavior,‎ in which case I am curious if that is true and what the common flavanoids are.‎

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Hi @CareyGregory,‎ added some info lmk what you think

Comment: This question is pretty much the same as your other question https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/24904/7951

Comment: @ak0000 Much better but didn't that first link you added pretty much convince you this question can't be answered? Chamomile flowers contain hundreds of compounds that could explain its actions and it's likely it's not just one of them but rather a combination, and nobody has analyzed the question deeply enough to answer it (and possibly never will). That's the problem with supplements: they're not drugs, they're not regulated, and there's little motivation for anyone to fund the years of research that would be required to understand them.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Yes, it is, but I think this is a (rare) example of a closed question resubmitted in acceptable form (after the edits). I don't think it can be answered, but I don't think it's off topic either.

Comment: @CareyGregory It seemed to me possible that the same way we understand caffeine to block the adenosine receptor,‎ it might be the case that an ingredient of chamomile like apigenin had an interaction with a neurotransmitter known to be inhibitory in a stress reaction,‎ and it seemed like possibly GABA and Fisetin were involved in the same neurotransmitters,‎ so it doesn't seem impossible that someone has put forward speculation as to whether multiple known stress reducers share the same activation site -‎ indeed,‎ I think the links I posted mention the idea,‎ it's just over my head.‎

Comment: @CareyGregory I hear your point about supplements lacking scientific research,‎ but often it seems as though if a substance has  major effect on psychology,‎ it isn't always impossible to narrow down the possible mechanisms it could be operating through – my understanding is that we understand many of the neurotransmitters involved in psychedelic drugs,‎ and for others there is at least speculation.‎